# How to recover tmux output?

Tags: tmux

I have a Play application that runs in tmux and its logs print on that terminal. I saw the last lines of it. It has generated only a few thousand lines of logs at most.

I want to **recover all the lines** of it from that running session to reconstruct the chain of sequence of an error. Failing that, I want to scroll back to instances of the text "to insert" so that I can examine them.

What is the best way to recover the output of tmux?

---

Play is a Java/Scala web framework. I have used the default development settings for its logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default operation of Playframework is to send logging output to both the screen and /logs/application.log http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/SettingsLogger. Consulting the log file with tools like grep and vim can sometimes be more helpful than scrolling through thousands of lines of buffered output.

If you want to be able to capture 5,000 lines of history in the scrollback buffer (default is 2,000), then put this in your ~/.tmux.conf file:

```
# scrollback buffer n lines
set -g history-limit 5000
```

Then to enter the buffer, you can do `ctrl-b <PageUp>` or `ctrl-b [`

Answer (score 3):

I don't fully understand you, but you normally could (default) Ctrl-b <PageBack> to see the previous lines.

I also recommend you using the `tee` command for demuxing tty output(s) to a mini log file and checking it later with your favorite pager or editor.

Comment: It seems to allow 351 lines of scrollback with `^b PageUp`. Can I see more output?

Comment: Sometimes I use precompiled packages for `tmux` and sometimes I build it, but IINM either case comes configured with 2000 by default for the max scrollback. So maybe you already did it!